# How to drop a column that has no data from a pandas datafarme

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a file which has several blank columns like this:

[image]

Raw data as text:

```
id  stage   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
1   base    A                   
1   s1          2   2   4   5
1   s2          3   3   6   7
2   base    AA                  
2   s1          5   3   4   3
2   s2          3   3   2   4
2   s3          2   2   3   6
3   base    B                   
3   s1          4   4   4   5
4   base    BC
```

I don't know the name of columns which are blank and they are a lot.

How can detect that D2 is blank (no data in this column) and then drop it?

I can iterate over columns/rows and find which columns are blank, but I think it is not the correct way of doing this in Python.

What is the correct way of doing this in Python?

Comment: `df.isna().all()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the keyword `how` you only drop columns where all rows of that columns are empty

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: this is not working if the cell has '' value ( a blank string). How can I detect that situation and delete the columns which contain empty string?

Comment: You can replace the empty strings with nans beforehand: `df.replace(r'', np.NaN)` and then apply the column kick

Answer (score 1):

Try with `dropna` , thresh here is require the column have one not null value.

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=1, aixs=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your entire dataframe for NULL values

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

For getting a NULL value count of a specific column

```
df.isnull.sum()['D2']
```

To Check if the entire column is empty you can equate to the length of the dataframe

```
df.isnull.sum()['D2'] == len(df)
```

Then you can drop the desired column

```
df.drop('D2',axis=1,inplace=True)
```